# Pandas Dataframe: area plot stacked='false' not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have an area plot that remains stacked even if I explicitly deactivate the stacking by setting the argument *stacked='false'*.

Here's some example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Generate sample data
sample_data = np.random.rand(24*365, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data,
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2015 00:00',
                                      periods=len(sample_data), freq='H'))

# Select date range to plot
date_from = dt(2015, 12, 22, 12, 0)
date_to = dt(2015, 12, 22, 23, 0)
df = df.loc[date_from:date_to]

# Plotting
df.plot(kind='line', colormap='Blues')
# Place legend topright
[ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked='true', colormap='Greens')
# Place legend topright
[ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked='true', colormap='Oranges')
# Place legend topright
[ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]

# This one doesn't work as explained in
# http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
df.plot(kind='area', stacked='false', alpha=0.5, colormap='Reds')
# Place legend topright
[ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]
```

The area plot looks like this on my machine:

[image]

I have two questions:

1.) How can I fix the area plot so that it's not stacked?

2.) Is there any way to get rid of the repeated " [ax.legend(loc=1) for ax in plt.gcf().axes]" after each plot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing `'false'` to `False` I'm not sure why it doesn't fail with `'false'`...

Comment: I don't know my way around the pandas plotting code to check, but I bet there is a `if stacked:` conditional someplace in the code and `bool('false') is True`

Comment: For 1.) Changing 'false' to False helped. Thanks!!!

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer Please answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Setting *stacked=False* instead of *'false'* solved the first problem for me!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from datetime import datetime as dt
mpl.style.use('ggplot')

# Generate sample data
sample_data = np.random.rand(24*365, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data,
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2015 00:00',
                                      periods=len(sample_data), freq='H'))

# Select date range to plot
date_from = dt(2015, 12, 22, 0, 0)
date_to = dt(2015, 12, 22, 23, 0)
df = df.loc[date_from:date_to]

# Plot
df.plot(kind='area', stacked=False, alpha=0.5, colormap='Spectral',
        title='Area Plot')
[ax.legend(('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'),
           loc='upper right') for ax in plt.gcf().axes]
```

[image]

If anyone knows how to fix the legend position (see original question), let me know!